# ArgumentException: SceneManager.SetActiveScene failed

Tags: unity-game-engine

```
public IEnumerator ChangeScene(string sceneName)
{
```

**Getting old scene**

```
    Scene oldScene = SceneManager.GetActiveScene();
```

**Declaring Objects**

```
    Camera oldMainCamera = Camera.main; 
    Camera.main.tag = "Untagged";
    AudioListener listener = GameObject.Find("Main Camera").GetComponent<AudioListener>();
    listener.enabled = false;
    // Start the async load
    AsyncOperation asyncOperation = SceneManager.LoadSceneAsync(sceneName, LoadSceneMode.Additive);
```

**Operation Start**

```
    while (!asyncOperation.isDone) // note: this will crash at 0.9 if you're not careful
    {
       


        if (asyncOperation.progress >= 0.9)
        {
```

**Save Preference player position to other next scene**

```
            PlayerPrefs.SetFloat("PlayerX", x);
            PlayerPrefs.SetFloat("PlayerY", y);
            PlayerPrefs.SetFloat("PlayerZ", z);
            PlayerPrefs.SetInt("defaultPosition", defaultPosition);
            PlayerPrefs.Save();
```

**Disable all objects here**

```
            AudioListener audio = (AudioListener)FindObjectOfType(typeof(AudioListener));
            audio.enabled = false;
        
            oldMainCamera.gameObject.SetActive(false);
       
            foreach (var go in oldScene.GetRootGameObjects())
                go.SetActive(false);

          
            yield return null;
        }
```

**ArgumentException: SceneManager.SetActiveScene failed; scene 'living_room' is not loaded and therefore cannot be set active**

```
        Debug.Log("There's bug in here");
        SceneManager.SetActiveScene(SceneManager.GetSceneByName(sceneName));
  

    }
}
```

Comment: Did you add the scene to the build scenes?

Comment: The error sounds quite self-explanatory: You are trying to set the scene to active while it is still not loaded .. could you format your question so it represents a compilable code?

Comment: I can go through other scene, but this message "ArgumentException: SceneManager.SetActiveScene failed" still spamming